# UberJump Tutorial SpriteKit error

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift2

I'm using Ray Wenderlich's tutorial called UberJump (https://www.raywenderlich.com/87232/make-game-like-mega-jump-sprite-kit-swift-part-2) and I've run into a logic error. The code used to remove objects is not working and I can't figure out why. I downloaded his source code and his code is not working either.

Here is what I'm having trouble with:

```
     override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {

    //new max height?
    //1
    if Int(player.position.y) > maxPlayerY {
        //2
        GameState.sharedInstance.score += Int(player.position.y) - maxPlayerY!
        //3
        maxPlayerY = Int(player.position.y)
        //4
        lblScore.text = String(format: "%d", GameState.sharedInstance.score)
    }


    // Remove game objects that have passed by
    foregroundNode.enumerateChildNodesWithName("NODE_PLATFORM", usingBlock: {
        (node, stop) in
        let platform = node as! PlatformNode
        platform.checkNodeRemoval(self.player.position.y)
    })

    foregroundNode.enumerateChildNodesWithName("NODE_STAR", usingBlock: {
        (node, stop) in
        let star = node as! StarNode
        star.checkNodeRemoval(self.player.position.y)
    })


    //calculate player y offset

    if player.position.y > 200.0 {
        backgroundNode.position = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: -((player.position.y -   200.0)/10))
        midgroundNode.position = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: -((player.position.y - 200.0)/4))
        foregroundNode.position = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: -(player.position.y-200.0))
    }




}
```

The "remove game objects that have passed by" code is not working. It is supposed to remove the platforms as the character jumps on them. Did I write the code out wrong? Thanks.

EDIT: Here is the checkNodeRemovalFunction as well.

```
class GameObjectNode: SKNode {
func collisionWithPlayer(player: SKNode) -> Bool {
    // Award score

    return false
}

func checkNodeRemoval(playerY: CGFloat) {
    if playerY > self.position.y + 300.0 {
        self.removeFromParent()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for the checkNodeRemoval function?

Comment: Is your `checkNodeRemoval()` method correct? Can you add it to your question?

Comment: Hi thanks for asking, just added the checkNodeRemoval function. @skunkmb

Comment: Hi thanks for asking, just added the checkNodeRemoval function. @claassenApps

Comment: Are the PlatformNode and StarNode classes inheriting from the GameObjectNode class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there could be an issue with your `checkNodeRemoval` function depending on how you're inheriting from the `GameObjectNode`. Something you could try is taking the `checkNodeRemoval` function out and checking directly in your update method.

```
// Remove game objects that have passed by
foregroundNode.enumerateChildNodesWithName("NODE_PLATFORM", usingBlock: {
    (node, stop) in
    print("found platform node")
    if self.player.position.y > node.position.y + 300.0 {
        print("attempt to remove platform")
        platform.removeFromParent()
    }
})

foregroundNode.enumerateChildNodesWithName("NODE_STAR", usingBlock: {
    (node, stop) in
   print("found star node")
    if self.player.position.y > node.position.y + 300.0 {
        print("attempt to remove star")
        star.removeFromParent()
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, but for some reason it still doesn't work. @claassenApps

Comment: Let's try to remove the casting of the node as either PlatformNode or StarNode and work with the node directly. Try and run this code with the print statements in to show if the enumerateChildNodesWithName is finding the platforms and stars and when they're supposed to be removed. See the edits to my original post.

Comment: Thanks so much, I did that and the only thing that printed were the "found platform node" and "found star node". "attempt to remove platform" and "attempt to remove star" did not print. @claassenApps

Comment: Ok, that narrows it down to a problem with the logic in `if self.player.position.y > node.position.y + 300.0 {`. Try reducing the 300 value to something lower. I'd start by removing it completely and working your way up until you find an acceptable threshold.

Comment: Good! Glad I could help. I would appreciate it if you would accept my answer - it helps me out.